# Service injection in a Symfony controller fails

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection, controller

I am adding a feature to a Symfony 2.7 application. I have a controller that has been defined as a service, and it in turn takes in another service. Here are the relevant contents from my services.yml file:

```
  app.service.video_derivative:
    class: MyCompany\AppBundle\Service\VideoDerivativeService
    arguments:
      - "@app.repository.video_derivative"
      - "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"

  api.controller.video_derivative:
    class: MyCompany\AppBundle\Controller\VideoDerivativeController
    arguments:
      - "@app.service.video_derivative"
```

... and the relevant code in my controller looks like this:

```
public function __construct(VideoDerivativeServiceInterface $videoDerivativeService)
{
    $this->videoDerivativeService = $videoDerivativeService;
}


/**
 * @param $id
 * @return JsonResponse
 *
 * @Route("/admin/video-derivative/create-by-clip-id/{id}", name="create_clip_by_id")
 */
public function byClipIdAction($id)
{
     $responseArray = [
         'foo' => 'bar',
         'baz' => 'qux',
         ];
     return new JsonResponse($responseArray);
}
```

... but when I pull up my controller in a browser, I get the following message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyCompany\AppBundle\Controller\VideoDerivativeController::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   MyCompany\AppBundle\Service\VideoDerivativeServiceInterface, none given,
>   called in /usr/src/app/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2200 and
>   defined

... so it looks like I'm doing something wrong. How would you go about debugging this?

Comment: Looks like VideoDerivativeService doesn't implement VideoDerivativeServiceInterface.

Comment: Show me your routing

Comment: Thanks.I have now added it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that what I needed was this annotation over the class:

```
/**
 * @\Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route(service="api.controller.video_derivative")
 */
```

Once that was in place, I got a much more helpful error and was able to move on with development.